# For an app memory, which is best pass parameters with intent or read a file?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

I am creating a native Android application with java and Android Studio.

The application create a file at the start with the information about the user.

I would like to know for performance reasons which is best to read the file once and transfer the information with Intent class or read the file on every layout?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how much data your file has. If it has some precise user related information with some countable fields, then you can pass that data via Intents. But, if your file is like huge number of pages, then it is not recommended to pass so much of data through Intents. Instead, you can read the file contents on each screen. Hope that helps.